# Replace mp4 file's audio with part of mp3 in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a around **30 minutes** `mp4` file and **1h30m** `mp3` file, let's say I need to replace `mp4` file's audio with part of `mp3` file, for example, starting from **30m00s**.

I have used the following `ffmpeg` command which works for replacing the `mp3` to `mp4`'s audio but not specify the starting time.

How could I modify it? Thanks.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.mp3 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k -shortest output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-ss` input option:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:30:00 -i input.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```